# Add simple quote in sql request

Tags: python, sql, syntax-error

I currently work on a project in python and I would have liked to make a SQL query with an apostrophe in my character string. Ex: `"Jimmy's home."`

And I have this error:

```
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax
```

So, I've tried to put a `\` before the apostrophe, but when I look at my database, just the strings before the `\'` are in my field.

String to in query: `"Jimmy\'s home"`
String in Database: `"Jimmy"`

I don't understand why?

Comment: Show us your Python code.

Comment: You need to use SQL parameters and have your *database adapter* take care of quoting here. Don't try and quote the value yourself. You need to show us your code and tell us what database adapter you are using.

Comment: I use "utf8_general_ci" for my sql field and TEXT. and this is my code :
`REQ = u"INSERT INTO organismes (`NAME_organisme`,`ID_organisme`,`adresse`,`cp`,`town`,`lat`,`lon`,`tel`,`fax`,`email`,`website`) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');" %(NAME,ID,LIGNE,CP,TOWN,LAT,LON,TEL,FAX,MAIL,URL)`

Comment: Please *edit* your question, don't put code in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been posted here and elsewhere many many times before, you must *not* use string interpolation to build up SQL strings. Use parameters intead:

```
REQ = u"INSERT INTO organismes (NAME_organisme`,ID_organisme,adresse,cp,town,lat,lon,tel,fax,‌​email,website) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);"
cursor.execute(REQ, (NAME,ID,LIGNE,CP,TOWN,LAT,LON,TEL,FAX,MAIL,URL))
```

Note, *no* quotes around the placeholders in the query string: the db adapter puts them in for you as necessary.

Also, please don't use capital letters for things that are not constants.

Answer (score 0):

You need use "Jimmy''s" to get your result"Jimmy's" instead of "Jimmy\'s" in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

because `' or "` is a special key, when you put it in your query the sql will automatically find where is the other `' or "` that's why there's what we called a `escape keycode` which is `\` the use of this is to display the next character in original value